# extension module cannot be loaded from memory but memory loading required

Tags: python, executable, pyoxidizer

I want to pack my application using `pyoxidizer`. I need to add `PySide2` to my package.

```py
policy.resources_location = "in-memory"
policy.resources_location_fallback =  "filesystem-relative:relative"
     
for resource in exe.pip_install(["pyside2"]):
    exe.add_python_resource(resource)
```

If I remove the line `policy.resources_location_fallback =  "filesystem-relative:relative"`, I get:

```
error[PYOXIDIZER_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE]: adding PythonExtensionModule<name=PySide2.Qt3DAnimation>

Caused by:
    extension module PySide2.Qt3DAnimation cannot be loaded from memory but memory loading required
   --> ./pyoxidizer.bzl:258:9
    |
258 |         exe.add_python_resource(resource)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add_python_resource


error: adding PythonExtensionModule<name=PySide2.Qt3DAnimation>

Caused by:
    extension module PySide2.Qt3DAnimation cannot be loaded from memory but memory loading required
```

If the fallback is defined, I get the error:

```
Caused by:
    resource collector does not allow resources in filesystem-relative
   --> ./pyoxidizer.bzl:258:9
    |
258 |         exe.add_python_resource(resource)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add_python_resource


error: adding PythonExtensionModule<name=PySide2.Qt3DAnimation>

Caused by:
    resource collector does not allow resources in filesystem-relative
```

This also applies for other packages like `Pillow`. I have not found anything to solve this issue and I'm not sure what this error message means.

### System Information

- Mac OS Big Sur, Ver. 11.5.1
- Python 3.9.7
- PySide2, ver 5.15.2

Answer (score 0):

I fixed similar problem by using

```
exe.add_python_resources(exe.pip_install(["pyzmq"]))
```

But at the end of the day it didn't work anyway due to missing library, see [indygreg/PyOxidizer/issues/339](https://github.com/indygreg/PyOxidizer/issues/339#issuecomment-1014632560).